# IndexError when using iloc

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm currently going through the index of a dataframe and then trying to select a row using that index. The code is as follows.

```
for index in clean_data.index:
    data_row = clean_data.iloc[[indx]]
```

However, I get the error:

```
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

The struct of my dataframe is as follows:

```
   game_week  game_day  game_month
1          2        15           1
2          3        17           1
```

The code handles the first index fine, but throws an error when handling a value of 2 for the index.

I can't use iterrows or itertuples due to the need for the index in the rest of my code.
I also need the format to stay as a dataframe, which is why I'm feeding the index inside a list. (It would otherwise return a series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By iterating over index, you use the index keys, not absolute positions. Either replace `iloc` by `loc` or iterate over `range(len(clean_data.index))`

What you do would work only if the index is 0,1,2,…,n-1 for n rows. This is not the case in you example that has 1,2 as keys (not 0,1)

Here is a practical example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(list('ABC'), index=[2,1,7])
>>> df
   0
2  A
1  B
7  C
```

```
for index in df.index:
    print(df.loc[[index]])
```

and

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    print(df.iloc[[index]])
```

both output:

```
   0
2  A
   0
1  B
   0
7  C
```

But:

```
for index in df.index:
    print(df.iloc[[index]])
```

outputs:

```
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```